# Homebrew Install Issue after computer restoration

Tags: permissions, installation, homebrew

I just got a new computer, and installed homebrew before restoring my computer with a time machine backup. When I restored it, I changed the main user file name. I think this is causing my problem.

```
Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 230481, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60411/60411), done.
remote: Total 230481 (delta 168814), reused 230474 (delta 168810)
Receiving objects: 100% (230481/230481), 52.92 MiB | 744.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (168814/168814), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Acceptable-Formulae.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Bottles.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Brew-Test-Bot-For-Core-Contributors.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Brew-Test-Bot.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/C++-Standard-Libraries.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Common-Issues-for-Core-Contributors.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Common-Issues.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/External-Commands.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Gems,-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-0.8.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-0.9.3.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-0.9.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-2.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/How-To-Open-a-Homebrew-Pull-Request-(and-get-it-merged).md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/How-to-build-software-outside-Homebrew-with-Homebrew-keg-only-dependencies.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Interesting-Taps-&-Branches.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Maintainer-Guidelines.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Press.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Python-for-Formula-Authors.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Querying-Brew.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/README.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/The-brew-command.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Tips-N'-Tricks.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/Xcode.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-tap.md' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-jenkins.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-pr.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-failed-test.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-block.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-console.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-tabs.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-for-core-contributors-trigger.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-passed-jenkins.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-passed-pr.png' (Permission denied)
error: unable to unlink old 'share/doc/homebrew/brew-test-bot-triggered-pr.png' (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master
```

This is the error it is giving me. 
I have already sudo uninstalled the old homebrew, "rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup", changed the file permissions, chowned the file "chown -R $USER on the Library in /usr/local/", moved the old files

```
cd /usr/local
# Moving old stuff out of the way.
sudo mv -v Library Library.old
# Now run Homebrew install script again.
```

as suggested in github questions (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/15138). None of this has worked! Ideas??

Comment: is it OK to remove homebrew and related packages completely and start over again? if yes try this script https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223

Comment: thanks! I tried that, but it gave an error-- see below. I also tried this uninstallation- https://gist.github.com/SteveBenner/11254428, and it gave the same "unable to unlink old 'share..' as above.                                                            'Alex-Taipales-MacBook:local alextaipale$ git checkout master
     error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten      by checkout:
 .gitignore
 .yardopts
 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
 CONTRIBUTING.md
 LICENSE.txt
 Library/.rubocop.yml
 Library/Aliases/0mq
 Library/Aliases/4store'

Comment: I posted an answer below, NOTE, use it at your own risk. WELL, if you just want start it over, it's fine to do, send me comments on how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, apparently my permissions and other things were very messed up. My uninstall was successsful-ish, but I was getting the same error when reinstalling Homebrew (as listed in the original problem). However, after the attempted install I could still run brew doctor-- which gave me the following error.

```
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:~ alextaipale$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
     cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:~ alextaipale$ cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: Needed a single revision
You do not have the initial commit yet
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:Library alextaipale$ cd /usr/local/Library
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:Library alextaipale$ git show HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I ended up fixing this by going through the following commands-- essentially removing my entire /usr/local folder and re-cloning the git repo of Homebrew,

```
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:Library alextaipale$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew (push)
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:Library alextaipale$ cd /usr
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:usr alextaipale$ sudo rm -rf local
Password:
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:usr alextaipale$ sudo git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
Cloning into 'homebrew'...
remote: Counting objects: 230841, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 230841 (delta 8), reused 10 (delta 7)
Receiving objects: 100% (230841/230841), 53.17 MiB | 716.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (168934/168934), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:usr alextaipale$ sudo mv homebrew local
Alex-Taipales-MacBook:usr alextaipale$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

Comment: wow, thank you for this post. This was the exact problem I was having after a migration from my old macbook to a new one.